# How to edit two bones position without affecting the mesh

Tags: rigging, bones

I already parented the armature generated by rigify and corrected the weight painting where it had problems, but after all that I just noticed that I placed the toes and foot bones incorrectly and if I move them where they should be, the foot deforms.[image: foot normal]

This is the foot in rest mode (already moved the bones)
[image: Deformed foot]

And this is the foot in pose mode. I tried different things like duplicating the body before everything and then after moving the bones, copy its weights. Also tried creating new weights thinking that could fix it, but it also deforms the foot.
Is there a way to move those bones to the correct position without affecting the mesh and without losing the weight paint I already painted?
[image: Bones I want to move]

I want to move the location of these bones because when the character will stand on tiptoe, it will deform incorrectly, but if I move them, the problem I said above will happen.[image: moved bones]

Comment: If in Edit mode you move an IK bone away from its controller for example, when you'll switch to Pose mode it will move in order to stick to its controller, maybe that's your problem here.

Comment: @moonboots added screenshots of the bones I want to move, and they are the toe IK and foot spin IK, in that case there is no other solution than editing the main armature and re-generate the rig, or there is a way to move IK bones? :/

Comment: You just need to move the IK bone and its controller together, or if you didn't do it, move the IK bone's tail to the controller's head

Comment: Rigify's bones are not designed to be edited directly.  You need to reposition the bones in the metarig and then re-generate the rig.  After that, some reweighting may be necessary.